# Entity Framework Core + Npgsql driver: Incorrect default GUID inserts if a complex alternate key exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using **Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** vesrion 1.0.0 and **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** version 1.0.0.

I have the following in my `OnModelCreating`:

```
builder.HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp");

builder.Entity<QuestionnaireLogic>().Property(l => l.EvaluatedAnswer).HasDefaultValue(Guid.Empty);
builder.Entity<QuestionnaireLogic>().Property(l => l.QuestionToJump).HasDefaultValue(Guid.Empty);

builder.Entity<QuestionnaireLogic>().HasAlternateKey(l => new
{
    l.ActionWhen,
    l.QuestionId,
    l.EvaluatedAnswer,
    l.EvaluatedValue,
    l.Operation
});
```

`EvaluatedAnswer` and `QuestionToJump` both have an empty GUID by default, but `EvaluatedAnswer` is included in the alternate key. The database is created correctly.

If I write explicitly:

```
QuestionnaireLogic logic = new QuestionnaireLogic();
logic.EvaluatedAnswer = Guid.Empty;
logic.QuestionToJump= Guid.Empty;
```

then after `_context.Logic.Add(logic);` `logic.EvaluatedAnswer` have new GUID. In previous version (rc-1 at least) the property was set to empty GUID as expected.

Is the current behaviour correct?

**Link to issue:** https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/69

Comment: Can you please open an issue for this on https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL?

Comment: I have just done it @ShayRojansky

Comment: Please link to the issue